# Converting x.trig to x.nt ot x.ttl

Tags: rdf, turtle-rdf, nt

I want to ask if there is any tool which can convert **trig file** to **.nt** or **.ttl** without losing any data.

Answer (score 1):

The crux of this is the qualification "without losing any data": Trig can represent complete RDF datasets, i.e., can contain "named graph" information, whereas N-Triples (.nt) and Turtle (.ttl) cannot. You could think of Trig as an extension of Turtle, so any Turtle file is legal Trig, but the converse is not true.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. So i have loaded the trig file to Fuseki tdb database, and I can do querying on it but i want this data to be loaded to virtuoso. And virtuoso does not support trig file, so i am wondering to download the whole data from fuseki as nt or ttl file. If you can point out any such tool or technique ...